# How we can have two parfor loops simultaneously in MATLAB to reduce calculation IDLE times?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor, idle-timer

Suppose that I want run my code using a `parfor` loop in MATLAB R2016a. first four iterations of this loop `(1:4)` has higher computational load comparing to second four iterations `(5:8)` so I have high differences in calculation time of these two parts.

How we can have two `parfor` loops simultaneously in this case? For example  second part of `parfor` loop `(5:8)` is doing it's job without waiting for completion of first part `(1:4)`? I want reduce the IDLE times using a new coding structure or any other tricks.

Comment: I don't understand what you expect parfor to do. The fifth iteration will be assigned to a worker as soon as the first four are assigned and a worker is idle, meaning that it will start immediately when you have more than four workers. Further it is not waiting for the completion of any specific Iteration.